# How to apply common style for controls through out the project

Tags: asp.net, css

I have defined a class in the Default.css and i wanted to use the same style for all the asp:textbox how should i do it

```
.myTextBox {        
color : #747862;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this style:

```
input[type=text] { color: #747862; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add css class to the text box
eg. TextBox ID="txb1" CssClass="myTextBox "